# Passbook Integration iOS (Dynamically)

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook

I want to integrate Passbook into my coupons app.

I was following this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1

We know for adding a pass we need to first create a `.pkpass` file.
I am able to create a `.pkpass` file manually for adding a pass to passbook.

I have created the `.pkpass` file by creating `pass.json`, `signature`, `manifest.json`, and all.

**But my real doubt is:** How to create a `.pkpass` file dynamically - if I have coupons like this in the table view (see  image), when I click on on "Add to passbook", I will provide necessary info and it will create a `.pkpass` file for that cell.

How can this be done?

[image: Screenshot]

How can I create a `.pkpass` file for a particular cell on click of an "Add to passbook" button?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because passes have to be signed using a private key, .pkpass files must be created on a server. In addition, Apple specifies a REST interface that should be implemented by your server to push and handle updates to these passes.

I don't know the details of your project, so you will have to decide what makes sense to you before you proceed to the next step. If you have a server that manages these coupons with a database and backend, you should implement the [web interface Apple specifies](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html) to build and sign your apps. If your coupons are relatively simple, you could consider using a third party service to build your passes. They will have APIs as well as tools to design your passes to make everything easier. You will have to do some research yourself but with a quick google search I found PassSlot and PassKit.

If you decide to implement it yourself you should read Apple's documentation on how the web service works and come back with a more specific question. (related to a framework, programming language, etc...)

Comment: Thanks for answering, my passes are very simple i don't want to use push notification to update my passes, also PassSlot the third party service which you are suggesting is paid and not free :( do u know any free api or any example to create `.pkpass` file which do not user server side programming ?

Comment: @Krunal, Asa is correct. An iOS application cannot create a working pass, it needs a server to do it. This is covered in the Passbook Programming Guide: "To keep your private key private, you sign passes on your server, not on the user’s device.".

Comment: @Krunal I am stuck with same issue, I need to create these passes dynamically, can you help me as to how you were able to tackle this issue

Comment: @Geet I have used this party api for creating pass.

Comment: @Asa I have a field start time and end time in my pass it will be changing for every time when I add the pass. Shall I generate the JSON file programmatically with my datas? Everytime when I click to add to pass, I want to create a pass wiith the information in the tableview cell. For this purpose do we need any server help?

Answer (score 1):

We need to use web services to get pass data and convert it into PKPasses on our side. Then use PKAddPassesViewController to add pass on your device.

Answer (score 0):

`pass.json` is a file you create yourself by hand. You can either follow your tutorial which shows what to include in the file or follow the Apple Passbook programming guide for building your first pass which does a good job of covering the topic:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/YourFirst.html

Comment: I have a field start time and end time in my pass it will be changing for every time when I add the pass. Shall I generate the JSON file programmatically with the datas?